# Sub command gets error for two same words

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I trying get result while using `!canada bob` and `!denmark bob` command. but it works for only 1 command and another one not working getting errors.

Error

```
in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument('{0.name} is a required argument that is missing.'.format(param))
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

Code

```
@commands.group(pass_context=True)
async def canada(self, ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await self.bot.say("No subcommand".format(ctx.message))

@commands.group(pass_context=True)
async def denmark(self, ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await self.bot.say("No subcommand".format(ctx.message))

@canada.command(pass_context=True)
async def bob(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("Pong".format(ctx.message))

@denmark.command(pass_context=True)
async def bob(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("Pong".format(ctx.message))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because you gave each subcommand the same name, so one was overwritten by the other.  Give them unique names, and use the `name` field of the `command` decorator to assign the name you want the user to interact with:

```
@canada.command(pass_context=True, name='bob')
async def canada_bob(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("Pong".format(ctx.message))

@denmark.command(pass_context=True, name='bob')
async def denamrk_bob(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("Pong".format(ctx.message))
```